# How to combine 2 integer value in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have following data:

```
a=1
b=2018
```

and my desire output is 201801 but not 20181, so any ideas can share here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn about `.format` https://pyformat.info/

```
a = 1
b = 2018
c = int("{}{:02d}".format(b,a))
print(c)
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://ideone.com/tzxePT)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
a=1
b=2018

c = b * 100 + a
print(c)
```

Output

```
201801
```

Passes unit test.
Requirements are satisfied.

Comment: lol. Well it does literally do what the question asks, although I very much doubt it is what the OP wants. Your format string idea is, of course, the real answer (well I guess it is based on the limited info available).